# Fivem Lua Error > attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'ZoneName')

Tags: lua

i have modified this version of Discord Rich Presence, this is the error im getting and i only have a client.lua this script , im very new to coding and i just need some help fixing this THANKS

**
i get this error when going above Z level 1300**

even with the 2.5 sec status update i have when getting this error and going back to the normal levels and waiting  more than the update timer it still doesn't update

SCRIPT ERROR: @custom_scripts/richpres/client.lua:26: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'ZoneName')

I have made line 26 in bold

this is the full client.lua

---

```
local WaitTime = 2500 -- How often do you want to update the status (In MS)

local DiscordAppId = tonumber(GetConvar("RichAppId", "*******************"))
local DiscordAppAsset = GetConvar("RichAssetId", "staticpfp3")
    
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    SetDiscordAppId(DiscordAppId)
    SetDiscordRichPresenceAsset(DiscordAppAsset)
    SetDiscordRichPresenceAssetSmall('info')
    SetDiscordRichPresenceAssetSmallText("The City Where Your Dream's Come true")
    while true do
        local x,y,z = table.unpack(GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId(),true))
        local zones = { ['AIRP'] = "Los Santos International Airport", ['ALAMO'] = "Alamo Sea", ['ALTA'] = "Alta", ['ARMYB'] = "Fort Zancudo", ['BANHAMC'] = "Banham Canyon Dr", ['BANNING'] = "Banning", ['BEACH'] = "Vespucci Beach", ['BHAMCA'] = "Banham Canyon", ['BRADP'] = "Braddock Pass", ['BRADT'] = "Braddock Tunnel", ['BURTON'] = "Burton", ['CALAFB'] = "Calafia Bridge", ['CANNY'] = "Raton Canyon", ['CCREAK'] = "Cassidy Creek", ['CHAMH'] = "Chamberlain Hills", ['CHIL'] = "Vinewood Hills", ['CHU'] = "Chumash", ['CMSW'] = "Chiliad Mountain State Wilderness", ['CYPRE'] = "Cypress Flats", ['DAVIS'] = "Davis", ['DELBE'] = "Del Perro Beach", ['DELPE'] = "Del Perro", ['DELSOL'] = "La Puerta", ['DESRT'] = "Grand Senora Desert", ['DOWNT'] = "Downtown", ['DTVINE'] = "Downtown Vinewood", ['EAST_V'] = "East Vinewood", ['EBURO'] = "El Burro Heights", ['ELGORL'] = "El Gordo Lighthouse", ['ELYSIAN'] = "Elysian Island", ['GALFISH'] = "Galilee", ['GOLF'] = "GWC and Golfing Society", ['GRAPES'] = "Grapeseed", ['GREATC'] = "Great Chaparral", ['HARMO'] = "Harmony", ['HAWICK'] = "Hawick", ['HORS'] = "Vinewood Racetrack", ['HUMLAB'] = "Humane Labs and Research", ['JAIL'] = "Bolingbroke Penitentiary", ['KOREAT'] = "Little Seoul", ['LACT'] = "Land Act Reservoir", ['LAGO'] = "Lago Zancudo", ['LDAM'] = "Land Act Dam", ['LEGSQU'] = "Legion Square", ['LMESA'] = "La Mesa", ['LOSPUER'] = "La Puerta", ['MIRR'] = "Mirror Park", ['MORN'] = "Morningwood", ['MOVIE'] = "Richards Majestic", ['MTCHIL'] = "Mount Chiliad", ['MTGORDO'] = "Mount Gordo", ['MTJOSE'] = "Mount Josiah", ['MURRI'] = "Murrieta Heights", ['NCHU'] = "North Chumash", ['NOOSE'] = "N.O.O.S.E", ['OCEANA'] = "Pacific Ocean", ['PALCOV'] = "Paleto Cove", ['PALETO'] = "Paleto Bay", ['PALFOR'] = "Paleto Forest", ['PALHIGH'] = "Palomino Highlands", ['PALMPOW'] = "Palmer-Taylor Power Station", ['PBLUFF'] = "Pacific Bluffs", ['PBOX'] = "Pillbox Hill", ['PROCOB'] = "Procopio Beach", ['RANCHO'] = "Rancho", ['RGLEN'] = "Richman Glen", ['RICHM'] = "Richman", ['ROCKF'] = "Rockford Hills", ['RTRAK'] = "Redwood Lights Track", ['SANAND'] = "San Andreas", ['SANCHIA'] = "San Chianski Mountain Range", ['SANDY'] = "Sandy Shores", ['SKID'] = "Mission Row", ['SLAB'] = "Stab City", ['STAD'] = "Maze Bank Arena", ['STRAW'] = "Strawberry", ['TATAMO'] = "Tataviam Mountains", ['TERMINA'] = "Terminal", ['TEXTI'] = "Textile City", ['TONGVAH'] = "Tongva Hills", ['TONGVAV'] = "Tongva Valley", ['VCANA'] = "Vespucci Canals", ['VESP'] = "Vespucci", ['VINE'] = "Vinewood", ['WINDF'] = "Ron Alternates Wind Farm", ['WVINE'] = "West Vinewood", ['ZANCUDO'] = "Zancudo River", ['ZP_ORT'] = "Port of South Los Santos", ['ZQ_UAR'] = "Davis Quartz" }
        local StreetHash = GetNameOfZone(x, y, z)
        Citizen.Wait(WaitTime)
        if StreetHash ~= nil then
            ZoneName = zones[GetNameOfZone(x, y, z)]
            if IsPedOnFoot(PlayerPedId()) and not IsEntityInWater(PlayerPedId()) then
                if IsPedSprinting(PlayerPedId()) then
                    SetRichPresence("Running around "..ZoneName)
                elseif IsPedRunning(PlayerPedId()) then
                    SetRichPresence("Running down "..ZoneName)
                elseif IsPedWalking(PlayerPedId()) then
                    SetRichPresence("Walking around "..ZoneName)
                elseif IsPedStill(PlayerPedId()) then
                    SetRichPresence("Chilling around "..ZoneName)
                end
            elseif GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId()) ~= nil and not IsPedInAnyHeli(PlayerPedId()) and not IsPedInAnyPlane(PlayerPedId()) and not IsPedOnFoot(PlayerPedId()) and not IsPedInAnySub(PlayerPedId()) and not IsPedInAnyBoat(PlayerPedId()) then
                local VehSpeed = GetEntitySpeed(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId()))
                local CurSpeed = math.ceil(VehSpeed * 3.6) or math.ceil(VehSpeed * 2.236936)
                local VehName = GetLabelText(GetDisplayNameFromVehicleModel(GetEntityModel(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId()))))
                if CurSpeed > 50 then
                    SetRichPresence("Speeding In a "..VehName)
                elseif CurSpeed <= 50 and CurSpeed > 0 then
                    SetRichPresence("Cruising In a "..VehName)
                elseif CurSpeed == 0 then
                    SetRichPresence("Parked In a "..VehName)
                end
            elseif IsPedInAnyHeli(PlayerPedId()) or IsPedInAnyPlane(PlayerPedId()) then
                local VehName = GetLabelText(GetDisplayNameFromVehicleModel(GetEntityModel(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId()))))
                if IsEntityInAir(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId())) or GetEntityHeightAboveGround(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId())) > 5.0 then
                    SetRichPresence("Flying over "..ZoneName)
                else
                    SetRichPresence("Landed at "..ZoneName)
                end
            elseif IsEntityInWater(PlayerPedId()) then
                SetRichPresence("Swimming around "..ZoneName)
            elseif IsPedInAnyBoat(PlayerPedId()) and IsEntityInWater(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId())) then
                local VehName = GetLabelText(GetDisplayNameFromVehicleModel(GetEntityModel(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId()))))
                SetRichPresence("Sailing around in a "..VehName)
            elseif IsPedInAnySub(PlayerPedId()) and IsEntityInWater(GetVehiclePedIsUsing(PlayerPedId())) then
                SetRichPresence("In a Submarine")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

i haven't really tried much as i dont know what to do

im so sorry if the post is not correct i new to these forums

hopefully it is allot easier to read now

Comment: Please use code blocks. The error mentioned `ZoneName` which is not present in your code. If the error would complain about `StreetName` the answer is: because its nil. Probably because the zone doesn't exist and your lookup returned nil earlier.

Comment: hey mate , sorry for the format of  the post hopefully it is allot easier to read, i had the wrong version of the code put up, i have now edited the post to the correct piece of code and hopefully its easier to read now, the code works but when i go above Z level 1300 - 1500 in fivem i get the error, if there is no fix i think it might be that the `GetNameOfZone` has the zones caped at a Z level of 1300-1500 but im not sure so if anyone could help would be great

Comment: Thanks, looks better now. Yes, as I said, `GetNameOfZone(x, y, z)` most likely returns a Zone you do not have in your `zones` map. You can either wrap following code in a if, or provide a default zone.

Comment: So I have got the `zones` from Fivem docs Native reference so I when I get home from work I will try to just use `GetNameOfZone` without using the `zones` converter and if I get some sort of abbreviation I know it works and that I need to add a new zone in my `zones` , I will try this and let you know thanks

Comment: I still recommend a fallback or default zone. You should not rely on a fixed set of zones :)

Comment: ok so i have changed the `ZoneName` to `StreetHash`  where the `SetRichPresence ` is , just to let you know the name streethash has nothing to do with a street hash its just `GetNameOfZone` , any way it works and gives me the shot zone name , and i checked and the short code name is in the `local zones` but when i switch it back to the original code at the top i get this error  **client.lua:26: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'ZoneName')** what can i do since idk what to do, i know the zone exists but it just wont convert the short zone name to the full name via the `local zones`